# Do Human Weapons take damage?

Tags: river-city-girls

When using the Human Weapon attack, a.k.a picking up an enemy and hitting others with it, does the wielded enemy get damaged?

Or are they damageproof and therefore a good way to keep recruit candidates alive until the end of the battle, for recruitment?